# Issues with setMaximumFractionDigits

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, fractions

setMaximumFractionDigits is not working with the following code.

```
NSString *input=@"80.90";
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber *number=[numberFormatter numberFromString:input];
```

number gets converted to 80.90000000000001. but I have put a limit to 2 decimal places.
So, how do I get number as 80.90, instead of 80.90000000000001

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setMaximumFractionDigits` and `setMinimumFractionDigits` used to formatting a number. or in other  words it get applied while converting a number into string i.e. `stringFromNumber`. So it will not get applied when you are using `numberFromString`

Comment: The only way I have been able to convert a number to a string and honour the maximumFractionDigits property is to do the following:

   [formatter stringFromNumber:[formatter numberFromString:@"$45.321"]];

This will return "$45.32", assuming that formatter is a currency formatter with maximumFractionDigits set to 2.

Answer (score 1):

As @SunilPandey mentioned `-setMaximumFractionDigits` is used for formatting a number. So You can do it like this:

```
float input = 80.99999;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:input]];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"NumberString: %@", numberString);
```

**Output:**

`NumberString: 80.99`

Comment: @Darrarski whats not working? copy paste this code to Your project and check out console.. You will get 80,99

Comment: @JustinBoo sorry I didn't make myself clear. The question was about converting string to number. Your answer proved that setMaximumFractionDigits works when converting the other way. It's not really helpful at all, and could be confusing.