# generatesDecimalNumbers for NumberFormatter does not work

Tags: swift, numbers, decimal

My function is converting a string to Decimal

```
func getDecimalFromString(_ strValue: String) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
    return formatter.number(from: strValue) as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
}
```

But it is not working as per expectation. Sometimes it's returning like

```
Optional(8.300000000000001)
Optional(8.199999999999999)
```

instead of 8.3 or 8.2. In the string, I have value like "8.3" or "8.2" but the converted decimal is not as per my requirements. Any suggestion where I made mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting `generatesDecimalNumbers` to `true` does not work as one might expect. The returned value is an instance of `NSDecimalNumber` (which can represent the value 8.3 exactly), but apparently the formatter converts the string to a binary floating number first (and that can *not* represent 8.3 exactly). Therefore the returned decimal value is only approximately correct.

That has also been reported as a bug:

- [`NSDecimalNumber`s from `NSNumberFormatter` are affected by binary approximation error](http://www.openradar.me/29923468)

Note also that (contrary to the documentation), the `maximumFractionDigits` property has no effect when *parsing* a string
into a number.

There is a simple solution: Use

```
NSDecimalNumber(string: strValue) // or
NSDecimalNumber(string: strValue, locale: Locale.current)
```

instead, depending on whether the string is localized or not.

Or with the Swift 3 `Decimal` type:

```
Decimal(string: strValue) // or
Decimal(string: strValue, locale: .current)
```

Example:

```
if let d = Decimal(string: "8.2") {
    print(d) // 8.2
}
```

Comment: Probably it is connected with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570756/issues-with-setmaximumfractiondigits ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk: That is related, but the main problem here (as I see it) is that `generatesDecimalNumbers` does not work (which seems to be a bug).

Comment: I'm not sure what is the cause of the issue.... out of 100, 99 times its proper but one time its failed.

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: Are you referring to your code or to my suggested solution now? Can you give a concrete example where it fails?

Comment: I have tried the answer of "Sunil Pandey". but no success. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @MartinR, Let me try with the locale, As without it it's not working for me. Please give me few minutes

Comment: @MartinR, My core data attribute is like: 
NSManaged public var personalRating: NSDecimalNumber?
Should I change it to Decimal?

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: Decimal is the new Swift 3 overlay type with value semantics. But Core Data still uses NSDecimalNumber for decimal properties, you can keep that as it is.

Comment: @MartinR, Yes both of your code is working fine i.e with and without locale, Thanks. I made some fixes for this which is also woking. Anyway changing my code as per your suggestion. (like)

Comment: @AshwinIndianic: If the string comes from *user input* then you probably should use the localized version. There are countries (such as Germany) where a comma is used as decimal separator instead of a period, e.g. `8,2`. If the string always uses a period as separator then you don't need the locale.

Comment: @MartinR, Got your point but this is not the case for this string. Thanks for your help

Comment: “`generatesDecimalNumbers` does not work” ... I’m not sure if I’d go quite that far. It does generate `NSDecimalNumber`, but inexplicably does it after (!) first converting the string to a floating point. But you can round the resulting `NSDecimalNumber`...

Comment: @Rob: Yes, thanks. What I meant is “does not work as expected” – I have tried to clarify that.

Comment: Using `Decimal(string: "156.89")` will still give me "156.78899999999995904".... this does not seem to work. https://i.imgur.com/n34O3PU.png

Comment: @Tieme: `Decimal(string: "156.89")` works correctly, but `Decimal(156.89)` does not (it rounds the floating point number *before* putting it into a Decimal) – compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781785/1187415. Try this: `print(Decimal(string: "156.89")!) ; print(Decimal(156.89))`

Answer (score 1):

I would probably be inclined to just use `Decimal(string:locale:)`, but if you want to use `NumberFormatter`, you would just manually round it.

```swift
func getDecimalFromString(_ string: String) -> NSDecimalNumber {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
    let value = formatter.number(from: string) as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
    return value.rounding(accordingToBehavior: RoundingBehavior(scale: 1))
}
```

Or if you want to return a `Decimal`:

```
func getDecimalFromString(_ string: String) -> Decimal {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
    let value = formatter.number(from: string) as? NSDecimalNumber ?? 0
    return value.rounding(accordingToBehavior: RoundingBehavior(scale: 1)) as Decimal
}
```

Where

```swift
class RoundingBehavior: NSDecimalNumberBehaviors {
    private let _scale: Int16

    init(scale: Int16) {
        _scale = scale
    }

    func roundingMode() -> NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode {
        .plain
    }

    func scale() -> Int16 {
        _scale
    }

    func exceptionDuringOperation(_ operation: Selector, error: NSDecimalNumber.CalculationError, leftOperand: NSDecimalNumber, rightOperand: NSDecimalNumber?) -> NSDecimalNumber? {
        .notANumber
    }
}
```