# Why NumberFormatter ignores maximumFractionDigits

Tags: swift, decimal, numberformatter

```swift
let src = Decimal(string: "130.975609756097560975609756097560975609")!
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 18
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 18
formatter.roundingMode = .up
formatter.locale = Locale.current
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let res = formatter.string(from: NSDecimalNumber(decimal: src))!
print(res) //
```

Output:

130.975609756098000000

What I expected result is

130.975609756097560976

Comment: NumberFormatter has bugs with Decimal values, see for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531014/1187415