# NumberFormatter return the wrong number

Tags: swift, numbers, formatter

I test the NumberFormatter to get the number from priceWithCurrency.

If price bigger than $70 NumberFormatter converted the wrong number.

```swift
lazy var currencyFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.currencyCode = "USD"
        return formatter
}()


let price = "$71.9"

currencyFormatter.number(price)
//71.90000000000001
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43538661/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do the same thing with 71.8, it will work. This is just because 71.9 can't be represented precisely in floating point numbers ( due to the finitude of bits )

Use integers ( price in cents ) or decimal numbers is the only issue to deal correctly with prices. Check the `Decimal` and `NSDecimalNumber` classes to see what you can do with this.

It is specially recommended if you do some computations on prices, ( If you pay 10$ with two friends in cash, two will pay 3.33, and one will pay 3.34 - so depending of your context, divide by 3 might not be enough)

```swift
let number = currencyFormatter.number(from: price) ?? NSNumber(value: 0)
var value =  number.decimalValue
var roundedValue: Decimal = 0

// Right way: ( choose your precisions - 3 decimals here):
NSDecimalRound(&roundedValue, &value, 3, .bankers)

print(number)
print(value)
print(roundedValue)
```

```
71.90000000000001
71.90000000000001
71.9
```

If you just need to log your prices, simply use `Int(price*100)/100`
It will do the job

If you need more... Good luck :)

**Edit**

Following the excellent remark of @Nicholas Rees, I add this variation:

```swift
currencyFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true

let number = (currencyFormatter.number(from: price) as? NSDecimalNumber) ?? NSDecimalNumber(value: 0)
var value =  number.decimalValue
var roundedValue: Decimal = 0

// Right way: ( choose your precisions - 3 decimals here):
NSDecimalRound(&roundedValue, &value, 3, .bankers)

print(number)
print(value)
print(roundedValue)
```

There, the result in the same when logged, but I suppose the internal format of the 'value' is correct

Another approach is to remove currency and create decimal from string:

```
print(Decimal(string: "71.9") ?? 0)

71.9
```

Comment: Won't parsing it as a float first sometimes represent it as the wrong number?   I would have thought parsing it directly into a Decimal was the only safe way to go.

Comment: You are right. I have added more cases. However, don't forget the real error in double value is around exponent -1000 - if I'm right.  The error when logged is due to rounding before display, but internally, it is insignificant. So computations are right unless you have billions of billions of dollars to count :) - You got a point anyway. Cheers

Comment: Sorry - precision is 2^-53 for common numbers ( according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format )

Comment: Thanks! I'm dumbfounded that Apple provides a currency formatter where the default is currencyFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = false.