# Swift NumberFormatter gives incorrect values with lots of extra zeros

Tags: swift, rounding-error, numberformatter

I found that for some strings the `NumberFormatter` produces incorrect results, as in the example below.

```
let input = "579.988"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.decimalSeparator = "." // added to make it reproducible for everyone

let output = formatter.number(from: input)?.decimalValue
```

*Result:* **579.9880000000001**

The error also appears for other strings. For example, "589.988". The error can be reproduced in the playground and an application, for Swift versions 5.2, 4.2 at least.

The `NumberFormatter` property `doubleValue` produces correct results, at least for strings that I tested; but the problem occurs again if I try to convert `Double` to `Decimal` (with 024 on the end).

Do you have ideas how I can approach this situation?

Comment: Presumably, whatever type `NumberFormatter` is internally using to store the result is not as precise as `Decimal`. How about switching to the `Decimal.ParseStrategy` APIs?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/43538661/1187415

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a [rounding error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) problem.

I would look at it from the practical side, which of course depends on what you are doing with those numbers.

Leave your string to decimal conversion as it is. Then, whenever you are displaying your numbers, there will be a conversion back to string anyways.
In Swift 5, there's the [`formatted(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement/3816389-formatted) method, which is easy to use:

```
numberValue.formatted() // "579.988"
```

If you'd like to fix the displayed fraction digits length, use this:

```
numberValue?.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(4))) // "579.9880"
```